# C++ : error with total+= in a while loop

Tags: c++, arrays, if-statement, while-loop, increment

I am new to programming and currently reading the book "C++ Primer Plus". Here is the whole exercise I did for a certain  chapter. The outcome of this code was not what I thought it would be(i expected that the **total** would just add the values from donations [1] to donations [9]).

```
#include <iostream>


using namespace std;

int main()
{   double total;
    int bigger=0;
        int values=0;
    double donation[10];

    cout<<"Enter 10 donation values(numbers only). ";
    cout<<"Enter first value: ";

    while (values<10 && cin>>donation[values] )
    {   ++values;
        if (values<10)
        {
        cout<<"Enter value no " <<(values+1)<<" :";
        total+=donation[values];
    }
    }
    double average=total/10;

    for ( values=0; values<10; values++)
    {
    if (donation[values]> average)
    {
        bigger++;
    }

    }
    cout<<"The average of the numbers is: "<<average<<endl;
    cout<< bigger <<" numbers larger than average. \n";
    cout<<"Bye";



    return 0;
}
```

Here is a sample of what I get when I run the program:

```
Enter 10 donation values(numbers only). Enter first value: 1
Enter value no 2 :2
Enter value no 3 :3
Enter value no 4 :4
Enter value no 5 :5
Enter value no 6 :6
Enter value no 7 :7
Enter value no 8 :8
Enter value no 9 :9
Enter value no 10 :10
The average of the numbers is: 6.15278e-311
10 numbers larger than average. 
Bye
```

Comment: "The outcome of this code was not what I expected" what was the outcome and what did you expect? Give us the values you input and the value you expect to be output vs. what actually happened.

Comment: What is initial value of `total`? Using unintialized variables is UB, but you should provide [mcve] anyway.

Comment: Set `total` to 0 when you create it.

Comment: I edited the question and included a sample output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a couple of errors in your code.

First, as [Pete Becker](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1593860/pete-becker) noted (and [Lightness Races in Orbit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/560648/lightness-races-in-orbit) refined), `total` isn't initialized, so its value is indeterminate. It could even be an invalid representation of a floating point number (e.g. a [`NaN`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/isnan) ) and it isn't for sure a valid starting point for your calculation.

Rising the warning level of your compiler would have helped you to spot this error. For example, with the command line parameters `-Wall -Wextra`, that's what clang++ ouputs:

> ```
> ... warning: variable 'total' is uninitialized when used here [-Wuninitialized]  
>       total+=donation[values];  
>       ^~~~~
> prog.cc:7:17: note: initialize the variable 'total' to silence this warning  
> {   double total;  
>                 ^  
>                  = 0.0
> 1 warning generated.
> ```

So, to follow their suggestion, you can just declare it as:

```
double total = 0.0;
```

Or reset its value before the calculation.

Second, your input loop isn't correct:

```
while (values < 10  &&  cin >> donation[values] )
{   
    ++values;            // <- Why is it here?
    if (values < 10)
    {
        cout << "Enter value no " << (values+1) <<" :";
        total += donation[values];    // <- Is this executed for the last (9) index? 
    }
}
```

You could rewrite it like this:

```
while ( values < 10 )
{
    cout << "Enter value no " << (values+1) <<" :";
    cin >> donation[values];
    if ( !cin ) // <- Input error, deal with it, somehow
        break; 
    total += donation[values];  
    ++values;
}
```

Comment: Actually, `total` can't have any value. Literally. It cannot have a known value. The value is _indeterminate_. If you read from it and get something that looks a bit like a number, that's just pure chance resulting from UB.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for pointing that out. Sorry for the poor wording.

Comment: Just being picky! Thought your answer was great.